# SSRS export report to excel without rendering in browser and remove hidden columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

How I can direct export report from SSRS to Excel (xls, xlsx) without necessary rendering it in web browser because report is too big and rendering is very slow?

And how I can remove hidden columns and rows from this exported report.

Comment: If my answer isn't what you were looking for, please include some screenshots/configuration and what you have tried so far so the community can provide a better answer.

Comment: What about delivering this as an Excel subscription?

Answer (score 1):

In order to export the report directly, you need to use a URL that will perform the export to your format. Here is the [Microsoft Docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017).

Here an example of the URL to export as XLSX:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML
```

The hidden columns and rows may be related to tablix rows and columns that are set to hidden. The Excel formatted report also includes small blank cells for any whitespace you have in your design. To my knowledge, you cannot remove them without affecting the layout of the Excel file. When I know a report will be exported to Excel, I include only the table/Tablix with no whitespace on the report. That produces a pretty clean Excel file.

Comment: yeah, i read this manual but not working on my SRSS

path http://localhost:8080/ReportS/report/CosMan_SSRS/CostsRep.rdl&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML

Reporting Services Error
The path of the item '/CosMan_SSRS/CostsRep.rdl&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help

Without &rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML reports opened correctly. I Use IE on Win10